# Why do I get an ambiguity error in this code?

Tags: java

Let's say we have these 3 classes:

```
class A { }
class B extends A { }

public class App {
    static void f(int i, A a) { }
    static void f(float j, B b) { }
   
    static public void main() {
        int i = 0;
        B b = new B();
        App.f(i, b);
    }
}
```

This produces the error:

```
App.java:11: error: reference to f is ambiguous
        App.f(i, b);
           ^
  both method f(int,A) in App and method f(float,B) in App match
1 error
```

Why does it not choose the type `f(int, A)` since `i` is an integer?

Comment: Why should it not choose the type `f(float, B)` when `b` is a `B` and `i` can be automatically widened to `float`?

Comment: @thatotherguy: Since conversions from `int` and `long` to `float` are potentially lossy, it would make sense for a language to regard a "precise" fit of the numeric type as more significant than a precise fit of a reference type.  Java's rules, however, were designed to prioritize simplicity over sensible corner-case behaviors, with the effect that passing a value of type `long` to `Math.round()` will yield a value of type `int`.

Comment: @RafikBouloudene: If an overload exists which for which *every* argument matches the passed value as well or better than any alternative, it will be used.  In your two-argument example, the first overload doesn't offer as good a match for the second argument as the second one does, and the second overload doesn't offer as good a match for the first argument as the first one does.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It is ambiguous because of two reasons:

- both overloads are *applicable*, and;
- neither overload is *more specific* than the other

Notice that both the `f(int, A)` overload and the `f(float, B)` overload can be called with the parameters `(i, b)`, since there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `float`, and an implicit conversion from `B` to `A`.

What happens when there are more than one applicable method? Java is supposed to choose the most specific method. This is described in [§15.12.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) of the language spec. It turns out that it is not the case that one of these overloads are more specific than the other.

> One applicable method m1 is more specific than another applicable
> method m2, for an invocation with argument expressions e1, ..., ek, if
> any of the following are true:
>
> - m2 is generic [...]
> - m2 is not generic, and m1 and m2 are applicable by strict or loose invocation, and where m1 has formal parameter types S1, ..., Sn and m2
>   has formal parameter types T1, ..., Tn, the type Si is more specific
>   than Ti for argument ei for all i (1 ≤ i ≤ n, n = k).
> - m2 is not generic, and m1 and m2 are applicable by variable arity invocation [...]

Only the second point applies to the two overloads of `f`. For one of the overloads to be more specific than the other, **every parameter type of one overload has to be more specific than the corresponding parameter type in the other overload.**

> A type S is more specific than a type T for any expression if S <: T ([§4.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10)).

Note that"<:" is the subtyping relationship. `B` is clearly a subtype of `A`. `float` is actually a supertype (not subtype!) of `int`. This can be derived from the direct subtyping relations listed in [§4.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.1). Therefore, neither of the overloads is more specific than the other.

The language spec goes on to talk about *maximally specific* methods, which doesn't really apply to `f` here. Finally, it says:

> **Otherwise, the method invocation is ambiguous, and a compile-time error occurs.**

#### More Examples

```
static void f(int x) {}
static void f(float x) {}
```

when called with an `int` are not ambiguous because the `int` overload is more specific.

```
static void f(int x, B a) {}
static void f(float x, A a) {}
```

when called with argument types `(int, A)` are not ambiguous because the `(int, B)` overload is more specific.

```
static void f(int x, A a) {}
static void f(float x, A a) {}
```

when called with argument types`(int, A)` are not ambiguous because the `(int, A)` overload is more specific. Note that the subtyping relationship is reflexive (i.e. `A` is a subtype of `A`).

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

- Type widening (1st parameter)
- Inheritance (2nd parameter)

*[Type widening](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)*: `float` is "wider" type than `int` therefore passed `int` value can be easily packed into bigger `float` box. It will not work in case, when we would like to "pack" `float` into `int`, as we can potentially lost floating point.
In provided case, having an `int` we can potentially pass it two both functions.

```
fFloat(float f){}
int intValue = 221;
fFloat(intValue); // inside f, intValue is treated as 221.0

fInt(int i){}
float floatVal = 221.221;
fInt(floatVal); // what should compiler do with remaining .221 part?
```

*[Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)*: `A` is a base class, while `B` is one of subclasses of A. So, when we declare method parameter as a base class, we can provide there both base class and its instance (but we will be able to use `B b` instance inside `f(int i, A a)` like type `A`. Hence, we can pass `B b = new B();` to both methods as well.

```
class A {
public void f() {}
}

class B extends A {
public void g() {}
}

fA(A a){}
B bInst = new B();
fA(bInst); // you can refer only to f() method, not g()

fB(B b){}
A aInst = new A();
fB(aInst); // you cannot do this, as subclass can have some additional
// stuff, that superclass does not have

//but even
A aInstBImpl = new B();
fB(aInstBImpl); // will not work without explicit casting as it is
// kind of A instance with B implementation - here polymorphism comes into action
```

Since all 2 parameters (from 2 possible) can suit to both methods without any explicit "action taken", the ambiguity error arises.